# How to make a container with the images mysql, wordpress and phpmyadmin in it?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, docker, phpmyadmin, docker-compose

The `docker-compose.yml` file is [here](https://gist.github.com/silviubogan/49913bd92dc7cda07782d473f621ade0):

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'abc'
      MYSQL_USER: 'wordpress'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: '...'
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 1111

  phpmyadmin:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db:3306
      PMA_USER: root
      PMA_PORT: 3306

  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:latest
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    restart: always
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: 'abc'
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: 'wordpress'
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: '...'
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_TABLE_PREFIX: 'wp_'
      WORDPRESS_AUTH_KEY: 'pune fraza unică aici ...'
      WORDPRESS_SECURE_AUTH_KEY: 'pune fraza unică aici ...'
      WORDPRESS_LOGGED_IN_KEY: 'pune fraza unică aici ...'
      WORDPRESS_NONCE_KEY: 'pune fraza unică aici ...'
      WORDPRESS_AUTH_SALT: 'pune fraza unică aici ...'
      WORDPRESS_SECURE_AUTH_SALT: 'pune fraza unică aici ...'
      WORDPRESS_LOGGED_IN_SALT: 'pune fraza unică aici ...'
      WORDPRESS_NONCE_SALT: 'pune fraza unică aici ...'
volumes:
   db_data: {}
```

I run `docker-compose up -d` and I get the three containers started. The first problem I encounter is that wordpress and phpmyadmin both use the `/var/www/html` directory. In the Logs section of each subcontainer in the Docker Dashboard there are no other errors.

Is the docker-compose.yml file correct so I have to remove the volumes with `docker-compose down --volumes` (this way removing the state information in the containers)?

I am an absolute beginner in Docker.

Thank you.

## Update 1

I can open phpMyAdmin in the browser with this section of `docker-compose.yml`:

```
  phpmyadmin:
    container_name: ...
    depends_on:
      - db
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db:3306
      PMA_USER: root
      PMA_PORT: 3306
```

But in the browser I get:

[image: screenshot]

> `mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'172.18.0.4' (using password: NO)`

Comment: I'm not clear what you're trying to do. The three containers should all start up fine and work fine, shouldn't they? Yes wordpress and phpmyadmin might both use /var/www/html internally but that's fine because they're in separate filesystems inside the containers. So using your docker compose file I wouldn't expect there to be any errors.

Comment: Please help me open phpMyAdmin in the browser. Thank you.

Comment: The title of the question suggests you're trying to combine everything into one container, but I don't see that in your compose file. Is that what you're trying to do? You probably can't combine the existing containers, each of which will have their own mini OS image; instead you'll want to start with an empty OS image and install all three services into it, or at a pinch start with one of these and then install the other two.

Comment: Oh OK: you need to publish port 80 from your phpmyadmin container to a local port number, and then you can connect to that. You'll need to add 'ports' entries to the phpmyadmin service entry in to the docker file and then `docker-compose run --service-ports` or you'll need to specify the ports separately on the docker-compose run line. [Relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36320172/243245).

Comment: I have updated my question with a new problem. Thank you for all the help.

Comment: @Rup I also posted a screenshot. Thank you.

Comment: You set up `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 1111`. Skimming [the phpmyadmin docker image docs](https://hub.docker.com/r/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/) I'd guess you have to set that for phpmyadmin too, or PMA_USER and PMA_PASSWORD.

Comment: @Rup Everything works well for me! Thank you a lot! If you wish you can post an answer.